# How to have glowing effects on D3 circle geopoint

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geolocation, geometry

Been playing with D3 for a few days. I got a world map drawn, and some "events" with geo that are displaying on the map.

Each event is compsosed of longitude,latitude,date

The date ranges is from june 1st to August 31st.

When event are added to map as time progress, I have a plain circle. However, I would like to achieve a nice glowing effect, to emphasis the current geo point being an event. (example here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssbQ2PVxGng )

So far I have come with:

```
svg.append('svg:circle')
.attr('cx', coordinates[0])
.attr('cy', coordinates[1])
.attr('r', 4)
.transition('next', function() {
d3.select(this)
.duration(300)
.attr('r', 7)
.attr('fill', 'yellow')
.attr('fill-opacity', .3);
})
.attr('fill', 'orange');
```

But I have no luck so far.

Comment: So you want to make the circle bigger when an event occurs?

Comment: Basically Yes. I want it to be radius 4, progresser to radius 7 with opacity, then progresser backward to radius 3.

Comment: Then all you need is to call something like `d3.select(element).transition().attr("r", 7).attr("fill-opacity", .5)` when the event occurs.

Comment: Thanks. when you say "when the event occurs", basically the event occur as the circle is created on the map, so Im not sure how to integrated this at that moment.

Comment: Then all you need is `svg.append("circle")....transition().attr("r", 7).attr("fill-opacity", .5)`.